# ASP.NET core connection string - use AWS RDS

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, amazon-rds

I would like to switch from using a local db in my web app, to aws relation databases (RDS).

I have connected to the aws RDS via mysql workbench.

In order to make this switch, all I have changed is the connection string. But it doesn't work. (it hangs for 30 seconds then throws HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway).

the local db: =`Server=localhost;database=ef3;uid=root;pwd=123456;`

But when I change it to `Server=test2.xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com;database=test2;uid=xx;pwd=xx;port=3306;`, I get the following output from the console. 
https://pastebin.com/raw/qA0py6t0

The last line says: `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware","{OriginalFormat}":"An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request"}}}`

How do I fix the connection string, to connect to the AWS RDS?
Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection seems fine, seems like that database doesn't contain the expected data.

From the trace:

**MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Table 'test2.Events' doesn't exist**

Comment: thank you so much for this!!! I have been tearing my hear for hours on this, the table was named test2.events (lowercase e). you are my hero :)

Comment: any tips on reading  that stack trace and finding the error? its pretty big and not obvious

Comment: Agreed, reading stack traces can be hard. I usually think it's easier to debug the code and see what's going on from there. As far as stack traces goes, try looking at one of the ends of those big chunks, and you are more likely find the origin of the exception being thrown.